# Angular 2: Set value to a variable from one function and get it in another in the same class

Tags: angular

I need to set myVariable value indicated inside the function load(), where I collect a data from the service and show it in another function (otrafuncion()), but I don't know the syntax.

```
export class clase{

  public this.miVariable:any;

   constructor(){}

   ngOnload():void{
     this.load();
     this.otraFuncion();
   }

   load() {
     this.loadService.cargar().subscribe(
     (respuesta) => {
         this.carga = respuesta;
         this.miVariable=this.carga.mivalorRecogido; //necesito este valor
       }
      );
     }
    }

   otrafuncion(){
   console.log(this.miVariable);
   }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand your point, the `cargar()` is asynchronous, so if you call `otraFunction()` before it load, you will have `undefined`. Do you need to call `otraFunction()` from a template or something like that?

Comment: yes, I forgot to put the function this.otraFuncion() inside ngOnload :___ (edit)

Comment: Your code it correct, but this.miVariable will stay undefined till the subscription is completed. The best solution here is to call this.otraFuncion(); inside the subscribe callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I can suggest a solution, your variable that you're interested in should be an observable, since it's only available asynchronously.

```
export class clase{
  public carga$ = this.loadService.cargar().pipe(shareReplay(1))
  public miVariable$ = this.carga$.pipe(map(c => c.mivalorRecogido));
}
```

now when you're interested in either of these properties, you just subscribe to them. the `shareReplay` operator will ensure your value is cached and only requested once, and will only be requested when it is first needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
   load() {
     this.loadService.cargar().subscribe(
     (respuesta) => {
         this.carga = respuesta;
         this.miVariable=this.carga.mivalorRecogido; //necesito este valor
         this.otrafunction(this.miVariable);
       }
      );
     }
    }

   otrafuncion(data: any){
   console.log(data); -> You will get miVariable here
   }
```

Also, in ngOnInit, if you call otrafunction, it would return undefined, since there is no `data` initially passed. First, you have to call `load()`.